# Serilog Correlate Log Messages package not compatible with asp.net core

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, serilog

I'm using a package "SerilogWeb.Classic" for Correlating log messages, but the package is not compatible with asp.net core, could you please guide me an alternative package, also I'm looking for Serilog metrics, could you please guide me for that package as well

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .Enrich.WithHttpRequestId()  // coming from SerilogWeb.Classic lib
    .Enrich.WithUserName()
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default log system of .net core `Microsoft.Logging` and in the startup configure the serilog, to do that you can use the package [Serilog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog/2.10.0) and [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.AspNetCore/) and the sinks packages to write somewhere, in your case to write into elasticsearch you need the [Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch/8.4.1).
You need configure your Program.cs to configure the serilog, [here](https://dotnetintellect.com/2020/09/06/logging-with-elasticsearch-kibana-serilog-using-asp-net-core-docker/) a complete example. But basically you need add:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Uri"]))
            {
                AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                IndexFormat = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToLower()}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}"
            })
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", environment)
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
```

And in your builder add .UseSerilog().

Comment: thanks, but my question was regarding ".Enrich.WithHttpRequestId()"  coming from SerilogWeb.Classic lib, this is not available in asp.net core